# Replace token inside word table using open xml using c#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a requirement in which I am cloning word table into multiple table based on  count and inserting in to word document. If I have 5 record it should add five table using existing table clone and replace token inside tables. It is adding 5 tables but it is replacing all five tables' content with the last record so all five tables have the same data as last row.

```
//Main code
string tableInnerText = tblMain.InnerText;
List<string> fieldsList = GetFieldList(tableInnerText, repeatedTableListName);

var parentParagraph = printBookmarkStart.Parent;
tbl[0].Remove();
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
  if (pageBreak.ToUpper() == "YES" && rowIndex > 0)
  {
    _wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(new Paragraph(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })), parentParagraph);
  }

  tblMainTmp = (Table)tblMain.Clone();
  _wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter<Table>(tblMainTmp, parentParagraph);
  _wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
  UpdateRepeatedTable(dt.Rows[rowIndex], dt, rowIndex, fieldsList, repeatedTableListName);
} 

[...]

private void UpdateRepeatedTable(DataRow dr, DataTable dt, int dataRowIndex, List<string> tableColumnsList, string repeatedTableListName)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtFunction = GetFunctionDataTable(tableColumnsList, repeatedTableListName);

        for (int j = 0; j < tableColumnsList.Count; j++)
        {
            string dtColumnName = ParseRelatedListFieldName(tableColumnsList[j], repeatedTableListName, true);
            string dtColumnValue = dr[dtColumnName].ToString();
            string formatValue = string.Empty;

            string replaceValue = dtColumnValue;
            //TODO: Check if fields a function field
            DataRow[] findRow = dtFunction.Select(string.Format("FieldName='{0}'", tableColumnsList[j]));
            bool bIsCheckBoxField = false;
            if (findRow.Length > 0)
            {
                bIsCheckBoxField = (findRow[0]["FunctionName"].ToString().ToUpper() == "CHECKBOX" ? true : false);
                formatValue = findRow[0]["Format"].ToString();
                replaceValue = GetFunctionValue(dt, 0, findRow[0], ""/*, null*/);
            }

            _clsLog.WriteMessage("Replacing " + tableColumnsList[j] + " with " + replaceValue, ClsLog.LogType.Log);

            SearchAndReplacer.SearchAndReplace(_wordDoc, tableColumnsList[j], replaceValue, true);              

            if (bIsCheckBoxField == true)
            {
                ProcessStandardFieldCheckBox(/*wordApp,*/ dtColumnValue, formatValue);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _clsLog.WriteMessage(ex);
    }
}
```

http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/search-and-replace-text-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document/

Comment: Can you add in your question the source code of UpdateRepatedTable? Also a short data sample input and the output you get.  Here we like having the whole context within the question. You might benefit to read the guide "How to ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Guillaume RAYMOND, I have updated code, and Input and output is Word document.

Comment: You haven't really asked a *question*, although the problem can, perhaps, be *inferred* from the last sentence. What, more specifically, are you asking help with?

Comment: Cindy Meister I have issue in replace while i process word using open xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolved this issue using DocumentAssembler (http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/documentassembler-developer-center/) in open-xml-powertools, which is suggested by Eric White.

DocumentAssembler is providing verity of option to process document for repeating contents, tables, Match conditions.